# How can CSR be generated just from private key?

Tags: csr

I followed a manual http://pubs.vmware.com/log-insight-25/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.log-insight.administration.doc%2FGUID-B3B00FE0-D943-459C-9859-CB68313D9467.html
I have found that CSR is created from generated private key. How can CSR's public key be just created from just private key? I think that CSR's public key should be taken from the key pair (public, private). Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: The [private key contains the information to generate the public key](http://serverfault.com/questions/52285/create-a-public-ssh-key-from-the-private-key). What makes you think that you would require both files, or even more important, **what is the actual problem you have**?

Comment: I just thought that both keys are needed. So I was wrong. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!